# Vulnerabilities due to improper use of cipher's mode of operation?

Tags: cryptography, exploit, vulnerability, cryptanalysis

I want to know if there was any vulnerability discovered - whether known to be exploited or not - in cryptographic systems due to improper use of the underlying block-based encryption algorithm's mode of operation. My question is not limited to AES or any specific cipher. Also I am not interested in academic-only vulnerabilities, i.e. it should have affected a real life cryptographic system soon after they were found

Comment: Yes, there have been many vulnerabilities discovered.

Comment: [CBC bit flip attack](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/66085/18298), similarly for [CFB](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/67207/18298) and [CTR disadvantages](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/85571/18298) and [AES-GCM IV-resue problem](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/84357/18298) and [It's catastrophic forgery problem](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/68525/18298) and  [CBC predicable IV](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/3883/18298), and [Sweet32 for 64-block size like DES](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/62772/18298)

Comment: [CBC padding oracle](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/72444/18298), [partition oracle on AES-GCM](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/88716/18298), [Message Franking on Facebook](https://www.iacr.org/archive/crypto2018/10993428/10993428.pdf) ....

Comment: This question is _way_ too broad. The entire reason that there are multiple modes of operation is because they each provide different security properties, and using the wrong one for the job will almost always result in a security issue.

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of examples:

- Given two identical blocks of plaintext, ECB mode produces two identical blocks of ciphertext (for the same key). This allows for a distinguishing attack where the equality of the blocks is revealed, i.e. an attacker can know that block A and block B contain the same plaintext, without knowing the key. The typical demo for this is encrypting a bitmap image of the Tux penguin and showing how the identical blocks reveal the image pattern; you can see this [on the wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#ECB).
- Without ciphertext authenticity verification (e.g. via a MAC or AEAD), ECB mode allows for replay attacks. An attacker can replace one block with another that was encrypted with the same key, and reorder the blocks in any way they like. The sentence "ATTACK AT DAWN! WE TRULY CANNOT SURRENDER TODAY." could be reorganised to say "SURRENDER TODAY.WE TRULY CANNOT ATTACK AT DAWN! "
- In block modes that effectively turn the block cipher into a stream cipher (e.g. CTR, OFB) the block cipher is used to generate a keystream, and that keystream is xor'd with the plaintext. If an attacker knows part of the plaintext, they can xor the ciphertext with that known plaintext to recover keystream bits. That's not a problem normally, because each message should have its own unique keystream. However, if you reuse the same key and initialisation vector (IV), also known as a "nonce", to encrypt two different pieces of data, the same keystream will be used for both messages, and attacker can use the recovered keystream to decrypt the other message.
- If you don't have any known plaintext, the same attack as above can be modified in order to distinguish which bits in two messages (encrypted with the same key and IV) are equal or not equal, when a stream mode like CTR is used. The attacker takes two ciphertexts and xors them together. The resulting sequence of bits will have a 1 in positions where the plaintext messages differed, and a 0 in positions where the plaintext messages were equal. This works because the stream modes xor the keystream with the plaintexts, meaning you get *(m<sub>1</sub> ⊕ k) ⊕ (m<sub>2</sub> ⊕ k)* when you xor the ciphertexts together. This can be rearranged to *m<sub>1</sub> ⊕ m<sub>2</sub> ⊕ k ⊕ k*, and since any value xor itself is zero, the *k* term drops out leaving you with just *m<sub>1</sub> ⊕ m<sub>2</sub>*, i.e. the xor of the two plaintexts.
- Without ciphertext authenticity verification, stream-cipher-like block modes are particularly vulnerable to malleability attacks. An attacker can xor the ciphertext with a "tweak" value, and the plaintext will be xor'd with that value after decryption. If an attacker knows a portion of the plaintext, they can modify that portion to say whatever they like using this attack.
- In CBC mode, if an attacker can modify the initialisation vector used for decryption, they can perform a malleability attack against the first block without modifying the ciphertext itself. This works simply by applying an xor tweak to the IV. The modifications made by this attack do not corrupt any other part of the message. Authenticating the ciphertext but forgetting to authenticate the IV is a common mistake.
- In CBC mode, if no ciphertext authenticity verification is used, an attacker can xor a block with a tweak value. Upon decryption the plaintext of that block will be corrupted, but the plaintext of the *next* block will be xor'd with the tweak. Later blocks are unaffected. This can be used in the same way as other malleability attacks, but it does result in one block being corrupted. This is still a very useful attack, though, because there are often systems where the desired change in behaviour occurs before plaintext validation, or where corruption of a certain part of the message has no effect.
- In CBC mode, if message authenticity checks are applied to the *plaintext* rather than the *ciphertext* (a construction known as MAC-then-encrypt) an attacker can abuse this. Since the system that receives the message must decrypt it in order to check it for authenticity, it cannot know whether a message was tampered with until after it decrypts it. An attacker can modify the ciphertext to try to get the system to misbehave during the decryption process. A common attack here is a padding oracle. Messages have an arbitrary length, but block ciphers work in units of blocks, so messages must be padded to fit. The system must remove this padding during decryption, and in the case of MAC-then-encrypt the padding removal must happen *before* authenticity verification. A common padding scheme is PKCS#7, in which the length of the padding is used as the byte value, e.g. 04 04 04 04 for 4 bytes of padding. An attacker can tweak the second-to-last ciphertext block to try to change the padding value to something else, e.g. 05 05 05 05. The system will see that the last byte value is 05, then check whether there are 5 bytes at the end with the value 05 in order to validate the padding. If it sees *four* bytes with the value 05, then some other value, it knows the padding was bad and it throws an error. However, what if the last byte of plaintext actually was 05? Then the padding would be seen as valid. That last byte would be stripped off during padding removal. Then the authenticity check would be done on the plaintext, and that would fail because the message was modified. However, if the system behaves differently during a padding error vs. an authenticity error (e.g. by returning a different error code), that difference reveals that the last byte of the plaintext was 05. This attack has been performed practically against SSL/TLS a bunch of times in different ways.
- Galois Counter Mode (GCM) is an [authenticated mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption#), which means it provides authenticity as part of the cipher mode. The authenticity is provided using a scheme called GHASH. In GCM, an initialisation step encrypts an all-zero block with the key in order to generate a value *H*, which is used with GHASH to generate the authenticity tag. If you reuse an IV with the same key for two different messages, the value of *H* can be recovered. This allows an attacker to forge all future messages.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, ECB-mode in block ciphers was shown to leak data.

> The message is divided into blocks, and each block is encrypted separately.
> The disadvantage of this method is a lack of diffusion. Because ECB encrypts identical plaintext blocks into identical ciphertext blocks, it does not hide data patterns well.
> A striking example of the degree to which ECB can leave plaintext data patterns in the ciphertext can be seen when ECB mode is used to encrypt a bitmap image which uses large areas of uniform color. While the color of each individual pixel is encrypted, the overall image may still be discerned, as the pattern of identically colored pixels in the original remains in the encrypted version.

[image]

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation

Comment: To be more precise, this is an example of a mode of operation that doesn't provide [IND-CPA](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/26689/54184) security.